# Passing form data from view to controller from a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm new to laravel and am working on an existing project. I have a form that passes data to a Laravel controller:

```
<div class="share_popup" id="share_popup">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="body">
                    <button class="x">
                        <span class="sprite close"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="sprite logo"></div>
                    <!--<strong><span id="item_shared">Item name</span></strong>-->
                    <form id="email_form">
                        <input name="share_email" id="share_email" type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        <input name="share_name" id="share_name" type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                        <input type="hidden" name="hint_id" id="hint_id" value="">
                        <span style="float:left;">Include a message below, if you'd like. test2</span><br/><br/>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message here..." class="description"> </textarea>

                        <button type="submit" onclick="shareHint(event)" id="share_button">Share</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a simplified version of the function that gets run in the controller on submit:

```
function shareHint($hint_id) {
    $input = \Request::input();
    $passedemail = $input['email'];
}
```

How does $input['email'] get the email address:

```
<input name="share_email" id="share_email" type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email" required>
```

as passed from this part of the form?

I don't see where the association comes from but it is passing.

If I wanted another form field how would I have access to it as part of the controller function?

Edit:

I believe Moppo is correct because this javascript is being run.

```
function shareHint(e, hint_id){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#share_email").val();

    var hinturl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "" + window.location.pathname + "?h="+data.currentHint._id; 

    var r = new XMLHttpRequest;
    r.open("POST", "/hint/"+ hint_id +"/share"), r.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if (4 == r.readyState)
            if (200 == r.status){ 
                $(".share_popup").css('visibility', 'hidden');
                $("#share_email").val("");
                $("#message").val("");
                //alert("Successfully shared hint with " + email + "!")
                $("#alert_error").html("Successfully shared hint with " + email + "!");
                $("#alert_popup").addClass("visible");
            }else if (400 == r.status) {
            var e = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
            //alert(e.message)
            $("#alert_error").html(e.message);
            $("#alert_popup").addClass("visible");
        } 
        else{
            $("#alert_error").html('Sorry, an error occurred');
            $("#alert_popup").addClass("visible");
        // alert("Sorry, an error occurred")
        }
    });
    var a = new FormData;
    a.append("hinturl", hinturl), a.append("email", email), a.append("message", $("#message").val()),a.append("_token", csrf_token), r.send(a)
}
```

Comment: are you saying that the input named `share_email` comes to the controller as `$input['email']` ?

Comment: @Moppo Yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: i've updated my answer

Comment: I believe I found the code altering input names, I added it to the question.

Comment: yes it's sent from the last line of the js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input named `share_email` comes to your controller as `email` it could be that some middleware modifies the request altering the input name. So you should check the app's middlewares and see if some of them is altering the request.

Alternatively it could be that some javascript code alters the input name before sending the form

**EDIT**

Looking at the code shows that in fact is javscript that sends the 'email' input:

```
var a = new FormData;
a.append("hinturl", hinturl), a.append("email", email),
```